# Waiting for a specific time [1.7s] without sleeping or freezing threads (C++)

Tags: c++

**Simple Question**
How would I do the following in [C++]?

```
float s = 1.70;
Do_Something();
[Wait for [s] seconds]
Do_Something();
```

**No freezing threads or sleeping**

Comment: Why no sleeping?

Comment: In the current case I have, sleeping will cause more issues, I have attempted to use sleeping but it causes a crash no matter which method I try so I'd prefer a method without it

Comment: There's no good way to wait without sleeping, unless you want to use 100% of your CPU for the time of waiting. Did you use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)? Are you sure the crash is related to sleep and not to something else in your program?

Comment: Re. `"I have attempted to use sleeping but it causes a crash no matter which method I try..."`: that suggests you have undefined behaviour somewhere else in your code.  Have you tried debugging the crash?

Comment: I am attempting to use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` currently, I will debug the crash and post results in a second, if it works I will also post the fix

Comment: "I have attempted to use sleeping but it causes a crash no matter which method I try" In that situation I propose to show your best attempt and ask why it crashes. Instead of asking how to do it without the most obvious tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the error was being caused by calling the wrong variable when I was attempting to use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`

the fix was using this: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<float>(time));`